# How to perform log(1-f)?

Tags: python

I want to perform the following calculation using curve fit in Python:

```
ydata = (-xdata * D) + log(1-f)
```

D and f are my unknown variables

```
def perfusion(x, D, f):
    return (-x * D) + math.log(1-f)
```

But I get either

```
ValueError: math domain error
```

Any other suggestions?

Example of my ydata = [-0.77103902 -1.25794411 -1.95109129]
xdata = [300,600,1000]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. There's no problem with `log()`. It must be somewhere else in your code.

Comment: That error means `f >= 1`, and you are trying to compute the log of a non-positive value.

Comment: It should be positive

Answer (score 0):

Is your 1-f less than 0? It's recommended to check the validity before carrying out error-prone mathematic operations.

Comment: It should be more than zero, but I will check it again

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```py
def func(x, f):
    return x*math.log(1-f)
```

(Or whatever your full function is)

As per the documentation for `curve_fit`:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html